# Converting .zip to .mcworld on iOS

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I found a map that I would like to download but idk how to change it from a .zip file to a .mcworld file! Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just change the extension from .zip to .mcworld**. See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MCPE/comments/5r8o19/how_do_i_modify_my_own_world_into_a_mcworld_file/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MCPE/comments/5amvgh/does_anyone_know_how_to_compress_a_folder_into_a/).

A description of the file type can be found [here](https://fileinfo.com/extension/mcworld):

> A MCWORLD file contains files that make up a world in Minecraft, a
>   popular block-building game. It stores multiple files, such as .DAT
>   and .TXT files compressed with ZIP compression. MCWORLD files are
>   typically used to backup a world or transfer a world to another
>   Minecraft user.

Comment: I did it and it imported to my mcpe game. It has no picture for the world, it says it was made on 12/31/69 and it has no title? This is the world I’m trying to import https://www.planetminecraft.com/project/modern-school-3992215/

Answer (score 0):

You go on a different file opener(like google drive or Dropbox). Then you delete the .zip and rename it .mcworld. It does not work in the built in files app.

Comment: The link is expired. Do you want this answer to stick around? Should it?